# How to handle parquet file (read&wite) in Android Studio?

Tags: android, parquet, chaquopy

I'm develloping an app with Android Studio and I need to send a parquet file to a server after gathering enough info (mostly FLOAT32 and INT4).
Does anyone know a way to write a parquet file in Android Studio?

So far I tried:

1. Building fastparquet and pyarrow with Chaquopy following [this guide](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/tree/master/server/pypi#chaquopy-packages), but did not succeed to do so (currently asking for help [here on git](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/482)).
2. Using org.apache.parquet and org.apache.arrow package to do this in Java/Kotlin but org.apache.arrow wasn't available in Android Studio
3. Directly integrate pyarrow and use the header to do it in C++
   But nothing works :(